# Do you know if eigenvectors of idempotent matrices are always orthonormal?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal, idempotents

I'm currently studying Econometrics theory, and I'm stuck in my problem set where it is asked if "eigenvectors of idempotent matrices are always orthonormal". How can I justify that?

Cheers.

Comment: Think of an example where it is not true. Hint: [Oblique projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Oblique_projection)

Comment: They are certainly not necessarily otho*normal*. Where do you have a scalar product from in the first place?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen When learning about matrices on this level, the "standard" inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is assumed (implicitly). Remember?

Comment: As posed, the answer is obviously no for *any* kind of matrix since any nonzero multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

No, and it's easy to construct an example where they are not. If $P$ is any invertible matrix, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $0$ and $1$ on the diagonal, then
$$ PDP^{-1} $$
is just as idempotent as $D$ is, and its eigenvectors are the columns of $P$. You're free to choose the columns of $P$ to be non-orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvectors need not be orthogonal. If you like to think of it geometrically, consider an [obligue projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Oblique_projection).

As an example, consider:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

You can check for yourself that it is idempotent. Since it is upper triangular, we can read off its eigenvalues on the main diagonal; they are $1$ and $0$.

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$. And $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $0$. The angle between these vectors is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ (or $45^\circ$). You can *norm* the latter eigenvector so it obtains unit length, if you like, but you cannot change the fact that the eigenspaces are not perpendicular. (*Orthonormal* means both orthogonal and normed.)

You can think of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ as an oblique projection that projects along the "skew" direction given by the second eigenvector onto the first coordinate axis (the subspace spanned by the first eigenvector).